# Right front brake hanging up

Tags: brake-calipers

2002 Ford F-150 XL 2 wheel drive 4 wheel disc brakes 4.2L
I replaced caliper, rotor/hub assembly, & pads on Right side, & pads on left side. 
Now, the right side will not bleed fluid. I bled left side & it worked fine. Took it for a test drive, and the left side will lock up, but right side doesn’t. Also pulls left when braking. Found no kinks in brake line.

Comment: Thanks people! I replaced the rubber brake line and bled the caliper like a boss! Brakes work flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

When you are unable to bleed a caliper, and there is pulling one way when braking, try loosening the steel line nut that is attached to the top of the brake hose.  If brake fluid comes out there, and not at the bleeder screw, then replace the restricted brake hose.

If fluid does not come out, then it is a matter of doing the same thing while working your way up the brake line.

It is not uncommon for a bleeder or caliper to not have the holes drilled all the way through making it impossible to bleed, but if that was the case, you would have low but equal brake pressure applied to both sides.

Answer (score 1):

The rubber brake line can become de-laminated inside and cause a blockage. It can be a solid blockage, a partial one, or a flap that acts like a one-way valve.
Two new brake hoses would be a good fix.